# How to make APC work with PHP

Tags: php, centos, alternative-php-cache

I have installed APC for php using

```
yum install pcre-devel
pecl install apc
restorecon /usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so
```

Everything installed correctly but still i can't see APC module in phpinfo

Answer (score 3):

Did you add:

```
extension=apc.so
```

to your `php.ini` file and restart your web server afterwards?

Comment: i did that its there. But its not showing in phpinfo. my apc.so is located in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a ready-made RPM to save you the hassle. http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories is a good place to start.